# Combobox = textbox + list

Tags: c#

I want to free type in combobox. When I stop typing I have a delayed task that populates combobox items with some input dependent results. The problem is that my input is overridden by the first item in the list. Is there a way to keep my input?

My sample code is going like this:

```
public void PopulateCombo(JObject result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        cbSearch.Items.Clear();
        if (result.Value<bool>("success") == true)
        {
            JArray arr = result.Value<JArray>("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                JToken item = arr[i];
                cbSearch.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem( item.Value<string>("name"), item.Value<string>("_id")));
            }
            cbSearch.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

**Edited on 23.06**

I'm giving an example of what I'm really trying to do.

1. Combobox is empty (no items)
2. User starts typing for example "ja". Combobox sends query to my backend. Should n't be a problem as the call is asynchronous with 1 second delay after user last input.
3. My backend returns some results (Anton Jamison, James Aaron, James Hetfield, etc., limited to 50)
4. I want to populate the dropdown list with results, to open it, but as a combobox text i want to keep "ja", so the user can clarify his search further.
5. User extends his search "ja h". Backend responds with James Hetfield. Result now is only one item and I can set the combobox text now or keep the behavior from above. Not sure which would be better yet.

All this is implemented but at step 4 when I populate the combobox using the function above, the text of the combo is changed from "ja" to the first match of the list. (Anton Jamison in the example). I'm almost sure that there was a simple option for implementing this behavior but I'm not sure if it was in C#.

On comments :

1. It was a good try but unsuccessful. Once I populate the combobox items my search string is changed to the first match of the list.
2. I think I don't try to implement the autocomplete feature.
3. Good catch about the DroppedDown. I move it in the edited version.

Comment: Can't you grab 'combobox.text' before you populate the list then restore it after the population?

Comment: Are you trying to implement auto-completion? If so, it's already built in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx

Comment: Can't repro the problem.  You might want to move the `DroppedDown = true;` line after the for...loop though.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the problem you talked about. The text in the edit box stays the same all the time.
I am using VS2008 though with a standard ComboBox renamed to cbSearch and its event captured (as well as the form's show event).
Rest works nicely.

Seemed like a nice task so I did it.
I also recover the selection, though you can see some flickering.

Most difficult was the synchronization - so I found an easy not tooo ugly solution.

Still, I don't do anything different from you.. maybe you start with a blank ComobBox again, maybe you changed some of the default parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cbSearch_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            allowUpdate = true;
        }
        DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

        volatile bool allowUpdate = false;
        private void BoxUpdate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                if (allowUpdate)
                {
                    var diff = DateTime.Now - lastUpdate;
                    if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 1500)
                    {
                        allowUpdate = false;
                        this.InvokeEx(x =>
                        {
                            if (x.cbSearch.Text.Length > 0)
                            {
                                x.PopulateCombo(cbSearch.Text);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void PopulateCombo(string text)
        {
            int sStart = cbSearch.SelectionStart;
            int sLen = cbSearch.SelectionLength;

            List<string> cbItems = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                    cbItems.Add(i + text + j);

            cbSearch.Items.Clear();

            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cbItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    cbSearch.Items.Add(cbItems[i]);
                }
                cbSearch.DroppedDown = true;
            }

            cbSearch.SelectionStart = sStart;
            cbSearch.SelectionLength = sLen;
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
            {
                BoxUpdate();
            });
        }
    }

    public static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
    {
        public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action)
            where T : System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do the same task with the hint of comment 1 + some tweaks. Here is my final code that does the work:

```
    private void cbSearch_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Dispose();
        timer1 = null;

        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    delegate void MethodDelegate(JObject result);

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(this.cbSearch.Text);

        Debug.WriteLine("Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["query"] = this.cbSearch.Text ?? "";
        this.session.rpc["advanced_search"].execAsync(parameters, results =>
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodDelegate(PopulateCombo), new object[] {results.GetResult()});
        });
    }

    public void PopulateCombo(JObject result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        this.selectedPatientId = "";
        string text = cbSearch.Text;
        cbSearch.DroppedDown = false;

        cbSearch.Items.Clear();
        if (result.Value<bool>("success") == true)
        {
            JArray arr = result.Value<JArray>("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                JToken item = arr[i];
                cbSearch.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem( item.Value<string>("name"), item.Value<string>("_id")));
            }

            try
            {
                this.cbSearch.TextUpdate -= new System.EventHandler(this.cbSearch_TextUpdate);
                cbSearch.DroppedDown = true; 
                cbSearch.Text = text;
                cbSearch.Select(cbSearch.Text.Length, 0);

            }
            finally {
                this.cbSearch.TextUpdate += new System.EventHandler(this.cbSearch_TextUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
```